# How to replace the first word from each sentence (from input file)

Tags: java, input, replace

My problem is that i have an input file and i must rewrite the text, in an output file without 4 words("a"),("the"),("A"),("The").I managed to solve it for "a" and "the", but not for "A" and "The". Could you plz help me with my code? Thanks in advance.
Below is the problem,the input and my code:

Problem:

The English, words "a" and "the" can mostly be removed from sentences without affecting the meaning. This is an opportunity for compressing the size of text files! Write a program that inputs a text file, line-by-line, and writes out a new text file where each line has the useless words eliminated.

First write a simple version of the program that replaces substrings " a " and " the " in each line with a single space. This will remove many words, but sometimes these words occur at the beginnings or ends of lines, and sometimes the words start with capitals. So, improve your first program so that it handles those situations as well.

C:>java Remover < verbose.txt > terse.txt

Note: there are various replace() methods of class String that would simplify this program. Try to write this program without using them.

input file:

A novel is a long prose narrative that describes fictional 
characters and events, usually in the form of a sequential story. 
The genre has historical roots in the fields of medieval and early 
modern romance and in the tradition of the novella.

Code:

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.io.*;

class File_Compressor
{
 public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
  {  
  int loc=0;
  String line="";

   File input=new File ("input.txt");
   Scanner scan=new Scanner(input);
   File output=new File("Hello2.java");
   PrintStream print=new PrintStream(output);

   while (scan.hasNext())
       {line=scan.nextLine().trim();

            while(line.indexOf("A")>0||line.indexOf("The")>0||line.indexOf(" a")>0||line.indexOf(" the ")>0)
   {
   if (line.indexOf("A")>0)
     {loc=line.indexOf("A");
     line=line.substring(loc+1);}

     else if (line.indexOf("The")>0)
     {loc=line.indexOf("The");
     line=line.substring(loc+3);
         }

     else if (line.indexOf(" a ")>0)
     {loc=line.indexOf(" a ");
     left=line.substring(0,loc+1);
     right=line.substring(loc+2);
     line=left+right;}

     else if (line.indexOf(" the ")>0)
     {loc=line.indexOf(" the ");
     left=line.substring(0,loc+1);
     right=line.substring(loc+4);
     line=left+right;}
     }
     print.println(line);
     }
 }
```

}

Comment: Are you allowed reuse the implementation of those _"various replace() methods of class String"_? ;)

Comment: Another note: don't look just for `"A"` , `"The"` and `" a"` or you might remove those substrings from words like Another, There etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A slight modification of your code might do the trick already. I didn't have the chance to read it thoroughly, but you could try this (expand for `The` etc.):

```
if (line.startsWith("A ")) {
 loc=line.indexOf("A ");
 line=line.substring(loc+2);
}
```

There are a few assumptions, though:

- Each line contains a single sentence
- There's only spaces used as whitespace (no tabs)

As a side note: your inner while condition should match the tests inside, i.e. you should look for `" a "` instead of `" a"`.

Another option would be to use regular expressions via the `Pattern` and `Matcher` classes, i.e. implement the logic of `String.replaceAll(...)` yourself - if that is allowed.

Comment: Thanks Thomas,startsWith Method did the trick! But why i cant read the first word with substring and indexOf? What do i miss?

Comment: @user2561683 you can, but you need to keep in mind that `indexOf()` would return 0 if the string you look for is right at the start of the string. So `indexOf("A ") >= 0` would be needed here (or even `indexOf("A ") == 0` to be consistent with `startsWith()`). If the string is not found, `indexOf()` would return -1.

Comment: Thanks now i understood! So if i wanted to use indexOf("A") i should write     if (line.indexOf("A")>=0) right?

Comment: @user2561683 yes. Note, however, that `if(line.indexOf("A")>=0)` would match any capital A in the line, not just at the start and not only as an independent word (e.g. the A in "America", "A." in Names or "case A" would also me matched) - that's why you should include the whitespace.

Answer (score 1):

Since you are reading the file line by line, break each line into an array of words

```
line=scan.nextLine().trim();
String[] words = line.split("\\s+");
String sentence = "";
for (int i = 0; i < words.length; i++) {
    if(!(words[i].equalsIgnoreCase("a") || words[i].equalsIgnoreCase("the"))){
        sentence += words[i] + " ";
    }
}
System.out.println(sentence);
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use hasSet class it has remove method so ı hope this mini example help you

My text:

```
The a a dssfdsfd The a the an fdfdggth
gtrfhtrht a the The fdsfddg
```

My output:

```
[fdfdggth, dssfdsfd, fdsfddg, gtrfhtrht]
```

public class deneme {

```
     private static  HashSet<String> hS = new HashSet<String>();    

     public static void main(String[]args) throws IOException
      {  
      int loc=0;
      String line="";

       File input=new File ("C:\\deneme\\inputstack.txt");
       Scanner scanner=new Scanner(input);
       File output=new File("Hello2.java");
       PrintStream print=new PrintStream(output);


        while (scanner.hasNext()) {
            if (scanner.hasNextDouble()) {
                Double doubleValue = scanner.nextDouble();


            }
            else {

                String stringValue = scanner.next();
                  hS.add(stringValue);

                    hS.remove("the");
                    hS.remove("a");
                    hS.remove("The");
                    hS.remove("an");          

            }

        }

         System.out.println(hS);
}       


}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with RegEx in one step. But i haven't the time to create an expressen. Sorry.
But normaly for that simple tasks i use apache commons lang.
In actual version 3.1 you will find the Class StringUtils with the method removeStartIgnoreCase, which you could use.

Example:

```
line = StringUtils.removeStartIgnoreCase(line,"a ");
line = StringUtils.removeStartIgnoreCase(line,"the ");
```

It's simple and clear i think.
My preferred solution would include to pack the words to remove in a array or something similar and then iterating over them to remove from start of the line.

Here are links to apache commons lang:

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.1/index.html

http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/

Comment: You should add whitespace ofter `"a"` and `"the"`, see my comment on the question ;)

Comment: Then do it, its your project. It's only a simple example for your problem. Expand it as you need.

Comment: It's not _my_ project ;), the comment was just a hint for completeness (otherwise someone could complain that it removes more than expected).